# conected to wireless but can't access any page

Tags: 13.04, wireless, ssh

I installed ubuntu 13.04 in an acer apire one notebook.  I can access my wireless conection and even i can use ssh but i can't go to any page using firefox or chromium.
Where is the problem?

Comment: Check your DNS settings.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there is some sort of Port Forwarding problem.
Check your port forwarding configuration and delete everything
then add back just what you know you need. 
Also check to see if you enabled using wireless or eth0.
If your connection is disabled you will experience this trouble as well.
Another thing is to check if there is a needed password.
You might want to simply delete all the networks and refresh
them then make sure you have entered the correct password
as well as selecting the correct security WEP, WPA, WPA2

Answer (score 0):

Try: `dhclient wlan0` I had exactly the same problem and it helped.

Comment: Without sudo it will not work.